# JS. Как записать в ассоциативный массив значения из обычного массива через цикл?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, for

Например есть массив a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]. Как, например, из него создать ассоциативный массив b = {1:"1", 2:"2"...} и так далее путём перебора любым циклом for / for of / for in.

Не совсем понимаю как записывать значения в ассоциативный массив. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: Давайте будем называть вещи правильно, как принято в языке: не "ассоциативный массив", а "экземпляр объекта", ну или хотя бы "объект". Разница есть, и она существенна для понимания JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так :

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  b = a.reduce((a, v) => {
    a[v] = v
    return a
  }, {})

console.log(b)
```

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  b = {}

a.forEach(e => b[e] = e)

console.log(b)
```